# The data from input dropdown select2 is not fetch into datatables

Tags: ajax, laravel

I did a multiselect input dropdown using select2. However, I dont really sure how to fetch the data that I call from database in the dropdown so that I can view it in datatable. Here are my codes:

Script for input dropdown select2:

```
 $('.ethnicity').select2({
                    placeholder: 'Select..',
                    ajax: {
                      url: '/select2-autocomplete-ajax_ethnicity',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      delay: 250,
                      processResults: function ($ethnicity) {
                        return {
                          results:  $.map($ethnicity, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    text: item.Bangsa_updated,
                                    id: item.id,
                                }
                            })
                        };
```

Controller for input dropdown so it will select the input typed:

```
public function ethnicity(Request $request)
{
    $ethnicity = [];

    if($request->has('q')){
        $search = $request->q;
        $ethnicity = DB::table("user")
                ->select("id","ethnic")
                ->where('ethnic','LIKE',"%$search%")
                ->get();           
    }
    return response()->json($ethnicity);
}
```

The above code only to select the data from database without fetch data to datatable. 
The controller below to catch data into datatable (I used this for simple dropdown, however dont know how to change so it is useful for above input dropdown.

```
public function fnFilter(Request $request)
{

    if(request()->ajax())
     {
      if(!empty($request->dataGender))
      {
       $data = DB::table('user')
         ->select('id', 'Fn', 'Ln')
         ->where('ethnic', $request->ethnicity)
         ->get();
      }
      else
      {
       $data = DB::table('user')
         ->select('id', 'Fn', 'Ln', 'Umur', 'Phone', 'Dob','St', 'Country','Zip','Ct','Jantina')
         ->get();
      }
      return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
     }

    $dataName = DB::table('modified_dpprs')
                    ->select('ethnic','Jantina')
                    ->groupBy('ethnic')
                    ->orderBy('ethnic', 'ASC')
                    ->get();



    return response()->json($dataName);
```

Blade is:

```
<select id="ethnicity" class=" ethnicity form-control select2-allow-clear"  style="width:200px;" name="namaDUN" multiple >
                                                                                                <option value="">Select</option>
```

My idea is to put the result from controller function ethnicity into function fnFilters. But I dont know how can do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can return response in select2 (controller function) required format 
like
$final_array = [];
$ethnicity = DB::table("user")
->select("id","ethnic");
if ($request->search != '') {
$search = $request->search ;
$ethnicity=$ethnicity->where('ethnic','LIKE',"%$search%");
}

// loop the results to make response
foreach($ethnicity->get() as $key => $value):
$final_array[$key]['id'] = $value->id;
$final_array[$key]['text'] = $value->ethnic;
endforeach;
return ['results' => $final_array];
// function ends here
and select 2 tag in blade file like this
$('.ethnicity').select2({
placeholder: 'Select..',
ajax: {
url: '/select2-autocomplete-ajax_ethnicity',
minimumInputLength: 3,
data: function (params) {
var query = {
search: params.term,
page: params.page || 1

}
return query;
}
}
});
```